# Did the Hachibi lose a tooth in Chapter 654?

Tags: naruto

Did the Hachibi lose a tooth in Chapter 654?

[image: Hachibi in Chapter 654]

Comment: It is better to avoid adjectives like latest and recent, since these will become obsolete in a week's time. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hachibi actually lost that tooth earlier in the battle against the Juubi. (Chapter 615)

At that time, Bee launched himself at the Juubi in his Hachibi form, and aimed a Bijuu Dama (Tailed Beast Bomb) at the Juubi's mouth. He exploded the Bijuu Dama inside the Juubi's mouth causing it great pain, but the Hachibi also took some damage, losing a tooth and yet another horn.

- **Hachibi about to attack the Juubi, still has its tooth intact**
  [image: Hachibi, about to attack the Juubi, still has its tooth intact]
- **Hachibi enters the Juubi's mouth with a Bijuu Dama**
  [image: Hachibi enters the Juubi's mouth with a Bijuu Dama]
- **Hachibi has lost a tooth and a horn after the attack**
  [image: Hachibi has lost a tooth and a horn]

Comment: You must have done hell lot of research for that! 
Nice work! :)

Comment: Well, yeah, to some extent. I noticed the 2nd horn missing a few chapters ago (1st one was sliced off by the Raikage earlier in flashback times ;-) ), then guessed that he might have also lost the tooth with the horn. So backtracked to find out where exactly he lost the horn and tooth.